# What is the meaning of "rabbits on the highway"?

Tags: the-core-2003

In science fiction movie *The Core (2003)*, Serge and the team's members are diving in a submarine-type ship through the depths of the Pacific Ocean to Earth's core. At one point, they were traveling downward in a spiral when Serge said these words to his team's members.

[image: Submarine diving in a spiral through the Pacific Ocean]

> We hit the wall, we're **rabbits on the highway**.

What did he mean by that?

Comment: Haven't seen it so I can't answer definitively, but rabbits on the highway tend to become roadkill. It means (literally) that they would be smashed and (figuratively) that they would be killed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbits crossing roads tend to be [transfixed by headlights](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=13885.0) of cars coming towards them.  They get scared, don't move, and thus become roadkill.

This is the parallel here in "The Core".  The crew members here are transfixed and helpless in their current situation and can't do anything except watch their own doom rushing up towards them....

Comment: This is almost certainly the correct answer, although the phrase that is more often heard in this context is something like "rabbit in the headlights".